# Offset not working with Laravel relations [Laravel 5]

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to take skip and take elements... Here is my try:

```
public function orderWhat($what){
           $this->what = $what;
           //QUERY FOR GROUPS AND PRODJECT_GROUP
           $userCondition = function($q){
                        $q->where('user_id',Auth::id())->where('project_id',$this->id)->take(10)->skip(10);
                    };

           //QUERY FOR COMMENTS AND PROJECT_COMMENT     
           $commentsCondition = function($q){
                        $q->where('project_id',$this->id)->where('order',$this->what)->orderBy('comment.id', 'DESC')->take(10)->skip(10);
                    };

                    $limit = function($q){
                        $q->take(10);
                    };
           //RETURN PROJECT WITH COMMENTS        
           $results = Project::with(['comments' => $commentsCondition,'groups' => $userCondition])
                                ->whereHas('groups', $userCondition)
                                ->whereHas('comments', $commentsCondition)

                                ->get();
           return $results;
       }
```

This will result with this query, but I will not get any result...

> SQL: select * from `projects` where (select count(*) from `groups`
>   inner join `project_group` on `groups`.`id` =
>   `project_group`.`group_id` where `project_group`.`project_id` =
>   `projects`.`id` and `user_id` = 1 and `project_id` = 1 limit 10 offset
>   10) >= 1 and (select count(*) from `comments` inner join
>   `project_comment` on `comments`.`id` = `project_comment`.`comment_id`
>   where `project_comment`.`project_id` = `projects`.`id` and
>   `project_id` = 1 and `order` = 0 order by `comment`.`id` desc limit 10
>   offset 10) >= 1

If I remove `offset` it will just take fist 10 posts....

Comment: Hmmmm man, I think that's more like a login problem, let me see if I can find it.

Comment: There may be other errors as well, but it looks like you're just offsetting the with and has calls, not the main query.